# How can I make the compilation log create a new window in Emacs? 

Tags: emacs, window, compilation

If I only have one window showing in emacs and use M-x compile, the window splits in two and I can watch the compile buffer easily.  However, if I have more windows showing, the compilation log takes over one of the others, which I find irritating.  How can I make emacs always split a new window to show the compilation log?

Edit: A bit more information from my reading that I've been doing.  It looks like compile.el calls display-buffer, which only splits a window if it is current full width.  Is there some way to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may modify the solution provided by [Trey Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745694/how-can-i-make-the-compilation-log-create-a-new-window-in-emacs/746071#746071) to fit your needs.

The following snippet marks buffer `*compilation*` as special, and sets a customized function as its display function to split current window even if already in a split window.

```
(setq special-display-buffer-names
      '("*compilation*"))

(setq special-display-function
      (lambda (buffer &optional args)
        (split-window)
        (switch-to-buffer buffer)
        (get-buffer-window buffer 0)))
```

Answer (score 3):

If what you're wanting is a dedicated top-level window (Emacs calls these *frames*), then this will do the trick for you. This snippet includes placement directives, but customizing the `'special-display-buffer-names` variable will get you what you want.

```
(setq special-display-buffer-names
      `(("*compilation*" . ((name . "*compilation*")
                            ,@default-frame-alist
                            (left . (- 1))
                            (top . 0)))))
```

Comment: I know the terminology, and I'm actually looking for a logical emacs window, as opposed to a physical one.

Answer (score 2):

Combining code from [How can I prevent emacs from opening new window for compilation output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309769/how-can-i-prevent-emacs-from-opening-new-window-for-compilation-output/28268808#28268808) and code from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompilationMode, this is all my code for `compile`, it provides you 4 features:

1). Use `compile-again` to run the same compile as the last time automatically, no prompt. If there is no last time, or there is a prefix argument, it acts like M-x compile.

2). `compile` will split the current window, it will not affect the other windows in this frame.

3). it will auto-close the `*compilation*` buffer (window) if there is no error, keep it if error exists.

4). it will highlight the error line and line number of the source code in the `*compilation*` buffer, use `M-n/p` to navigate every error in `*compilation*` buffer, `Enter` in the error line to jump to the line in your code code.

```
(require 'compile)
(setq compilation-last-buffer nil)
(defun compile-again (ARG)
  "Run the same compile as the last time.

If there is no last time, or there is a prefix argument, this acts like M-x compile."
  (interactive "p")
  (if (and (eq ARG 1)
           compilation-last-buffer)
      (progn
        (set-buffer compilation-last-buffer)
        (revert-buffer t t))
    (progn
      (call-interactively 'compile)
      (setq cur (selected-window))
      (setq w (get-buffer-window "*compilation*"))
      (select-window w)
      (setq h (window-height w))
      (shrink-window (- h 10))
      (select-window cur))))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-m") 'compile-again)
(defun my-compilation-hook ()
  "Make sure that the compile window is splitting vertically."
  (progn
    (if (not (get-buffer-window "*compilation*"))
        (progn
          (split-window-vertically)))))
(add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook 'my-compilation-hook)
(defun compilation-exit-autoclose (STATUS code msg)
  "Close the compilation window if there was no error at all."
  ;; If M-x compile exists with a 0
  (when (and (eq STATUS 'exit) (zerop code))
    ;; then bury the *compilation* buffer, so that C-x b doesn't go there
    (bury-buffer)
    ;; and delete the *compilation* window
    (delete-window (get-buffer-window (get-buffer "*compilation*"))))
  ;; Always return the anticipated result of compilation-exit-message-function
  (cons msg code))
(setq compilation-exit-message-function 'compilation-exit-autoclose)
(defvar all-overlays ())
(defun delete-this-overlay(overlay is-after begin end &optional len)
  (delete-overlay overlay)
  )
(defun highlight-current-line ()
"Highlight current line."
  (interactive)
  (setq current-point (point))
  (beginning-of-line)
  (setq beg (point))
  (forward-line 1)
  (setq end (point))
  ;; Create and place the overlay
  (setq error-line-overlay (make-overlay 1 1))

  ;; Append to list of all overlays
  (setq all-overlays (cons error-line-overlay all-overlays))

  (overlay-put error-line-overlay
               'face '(background-color . "red"))
  (overlay-put error-line-overlay
               'modification-hooks (list 'delete-this-overlay))
  (move-overlay error-line-overlay beg end)
  (goto-char current-point))
(defun delete-all-overlays ()
  "Delete all overlays"
  (while all-overlays
    (delete-overlay (car all-overlays))
    (setq all-overlays (cdr all-overlays))))
(defun highlight-error-lines(compilation-buffer process-result)
  (interactive)
  (delete-all-overlays)
  (condition-case nil
      (while t
        (next-error)
        (highlight-current-line))
    (error nil)))
(setq compilation-finish-functions 'highlight-error-lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `smart-compile` package inside Emacs.

add this into your `init.el` or `.emacs`

```
(require 'compile)
(setq compilation-last-buffer nil)
;; save all modified buffers without asking before compilation
(setq compilation-ask-about-save nil)
(defun compile-again (ARG)
  "Run the same compile as the last time.

With a prefix argument or no last time, this acts like M-x compile,
and you can reconfigure the compile args."
  (interactive "p")
  ;; the following two lines create bug: split a new window every time
  ;; (if (not (get-buffer-window "*compilation*"))
  ;;      (split-window-below))
  (if (and (eq ARG 1) compilation-last-buffer)
      (recompile)
    (call-interactively 'smart-compile)))
(bind-key* "C-x C-m" 'compile-again)
;; create a new small frame to show the compilation info
;; will be auto closed if no error
(setq special-display-buffer-names
      `(("*compilation*" . ((name . "*compilation*")
                            ,@default-frame-alist
                            (left . (- 1))
                            (top . 0)))))
(setq compilation-finish-functions
      (lambda (buf str)
        (if (null (string-match ".*exited abnormally.*" str))
            ;;no errors, make the compilation window go away in a few seconds
            (progn
              (run-at-time
               "1 sec" nil 'delete-windows-on
               (get-buffer-create "*compilation*"))
              (message "No Compilation Errors!")))))
```

Use `C-x C-m` to compile your source code, If you are the first time to execute `C-x C-m`, it will ask you to change the default command (which is usually enough), otherwise it will execute the command you just used to compile directly and you have to use `C-u C-x C-m` to change the command if you want. If you got a `Makefile` inside the current directory, it will notice and prompt to ask whether you want to use it.

Maybe this answer is too much for your question, but please try it.