# How can I prevent emacs from opening new window for compilation output?

Tags: emacs

How can I prevent emacs from opening new window when I invoke compile command?
I would like to bind it to a particular existing window.

Answer (score 9):

Based on your comments with Luke, I would recommend checking out this function that I use.  I like it because it buries the compilation buffer if there were no errors, otherwise it leaves it up so you can see them.

You can check emacs wiki for the page, but here is the code:

```
;; Helper for compilation. Close the compilation window if
;; there was no error at all. (emacs wiki)
(defun compilation-exit-autoclose (status code msg)
  ;; If M-x compile exists with a 0
  (when (and (eq status 'exit) (zerop code))
    ;; then bury the *compilation* buffer, so that C-x b doesn't go there
    (bury-buffer)
    ;; and delete the *compilation* window
    (delete-window (get-buffer-window (get-buffer "*compilation*"))))
  ;; Always return the anticipated result of compilation-exit-message-function
  (cons msg code))
;; Specify my function (maybe I should have done a lambda function)
(setq compilation-exit-message-function 'compilation-exit-autoclose)
```

You can always switch back to the compilation buffer to view any warnings.

Comment: Umm, thanks, but there's small problem with this approach. Imagine you have 2 windows open side by side. You start compilation in left window -- it opens up in right window. After compilation is end -- you want to get window with your code back, while this script would just close it (also annoying). Anyway, I should improve my ELisp and do the right thing probably.

Comment: @KonstantineRybnikov http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745694/how-can-i-make-the-compilation-log-create-a-new-window-in-emacs

Answer (score 3):

You can chose the name of the compilation buffer by setting `compilation-buffer-name-function` to a function which takes the name of the major mode and returns a buffer name:

```
(setq compilation-buffer-name-function 
      '(lambda (maj-mode)
     "existing-buffer-name"))
```

However, looking at the source code for `compliation-start`, it looks like the compilation buffer is always cleared (by calling `erase-buffer`) before the output is written.

**Edit**: If I understand the question correctly, you need to hack the function `compilation-start` in your `compile.el` file by commenting out a line:

```
    ;; Pop up the compilation buffer.
    ;; http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2007-11/msg01638.html
    ;; (setq outwin (display-buffer outbuf))
```

Comment: I'm ok with *compilation* name. I'm just not ok with "compile" opening new window whenever *compilation* is not visible.

Comment: OK, so you don't want the \*compilation\* buffer to be popped up automatically? See my edited answer.

Comment: It's not good to comment things in default emacs lisp files. You should rather ``defadvice`` it.

Comment: ``(defadvice compilation-start (around inhidbit-display (command &optional mode name-function highlight-regexp)) (flet ((display-buffer)) (fset 'display-buffer 'ignore) ad-do-it)) (ad-activate 'compilation-start) (ad-deactivate 'compilation-start)`` You can also set your function in the place of ``'ignore`` if you wish. It will take ``display-buffer`` arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Not too sure what you're asking, but if you want buffer `*compilation*' to be shown in the current window, instead of being shown in a different window, then:

```
(add-to-list 'same-window-buffer-names "*compilation*")
```

Comment: OP is asking for opening it in another existing window, NOT the same one.

Answer (score 1):

Combining @zdav 's anwser and code from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompilationMode, this is all my code for `compile`, it provides you 4 features:

1). Use `compile-again` to run the same compile as the last time automatically, no prompt. If there is no last time, or there is a prefix argument, it acts like M-x compile.

2). `compile` will split the current window, it will not affect the other windows in this frame.

3). it will auto-close the `*compilation*` buffer (window) if there is no error, keep it if error exists.

4). it will highlight the error line and line number of the source code in the `*compilation*` buffer, use `M-n/p` to navigate every error in `*compilation*` buffer, `Enter` in the error line to jump to the line in your code code.

```
(require 'compile)
(setq compilation-last-buffer nil)
(defun compile-again (ARG)
  "Run the same compile as the last time.

If there is no last time, or there is a prefix argument, this acts like M-x compile."
  (interactive "p")
  (if (and (eq ARG 1)
           compilation-last-buffer)
      (progn
        (set-buffer compilation-last-buffer)
        (revert-buffer t t))
    (progn
      (call-interactively 'compile)
      (setq cur (selected-window))
      (setq w (get-buffer-window "*compilation*"))
      (select-window w)
      (setq h (window-height w))
      (shrink-window (- h 10))
      (select-window cur))))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-m") 'compile-again)
(defun my-compilation-hook ()
  "Make sure that the compile window is splitting vertically."
  (progn
    (if (not (get-buffer-window "*compilation*"))
        (progn
          (split-window-vertically)))))
(add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook 'my-compilation-hook)
(defun compilation-exit-autoclose (STATUS code msg)
  "Close the compilation window if there was no error at all."
  ;; If M-x compile exists with a 0
  (when (and (eq STATUS 'exit) (zerop code))
    ;; then bury the *compilation* buffer, so that C-x b doesn't go there
    (bury-buffer)
    ;; and delete the *compilation* window
    (delete-window (get-buffer-window (get-buffer "*compilation*"))))
  ;; Always return the anticipated result of compilation-exit-message-function
  (cons msg code))
(setq compilation-exit-message-function 'compilation-exit-autoclose)
(defvar all-overlays ())
(defun delete-this-overlay(overlay is-after begin end &optional len)
  (delete-overlay overlay)
  )
(defun highlight-current-line ()
"Highlight current line."
  (interactive)
  (setq current-point (point))
  (beginning-of-line)
  (setq beg (point))
  (forward-line 1)
  (setq end (point))
  ;; Create and place the overlay
  (setq error-line-overlay (make-overlay 1 1))

  ;; Append to list of all overlays
  (setq all-overlays (cons error-line-overlay all-overlays))

  (overlay-put error-line-overlay
               'face '(background-color . "red"))
  (overlay-put error-line-overlay
               'modification-hooks (list 'delete-this-overlay))
  (move-overlay error-line-overlay beg end)
  (goto-char current-point))
(defun delete-all-overlays ()
  "Delete all overlays"
  (while all-overlays
    (delete-overlay (car all-overlays))
    (setq all-overlays (cdr all-overlays))))
(defun highlight-error-lines(compilation-buffer process-result)
  (interactive)
  (delete-all-overlays)
  (condition-case nil
      (while t
        (next-error)
        (highlight-current-line))
    (error nil)))
(setq compilation-finish-functions 'highlight-error-lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked similar question for another case (Man mode) but mayhaps the code will be of use also here: 
[Managing Emacs *Man* buffer location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309340/managing-emacs-man-buffer-location/28311686)
(in particular https://gist.github.com/Mekk/aad77cf3401a17e5df0d but check question above )